# nginx gzip doesnt work for GET method, but work for POST method

Tags: post, nginx, get, gzip

I got a problem on nginx 0.9.6 (centos) about gzip, when i use POST method, the gzip  works, but but when i use GET method, it doesnt work. the tested page is text/html page, the nginx.conf:

```
    gzip            on;
gzip_min_length 1k;
gzip_buffers    4 16k;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_types      text/plain text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
gzip_vary       on;
gzip_proxied    any;
gzip_disable    "msie6";
```

appreciate your replying. please let's me know you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a year ago, but you just need to add text/html to the gzip_types list.